# Task not running in grunt-contrib-uglify

Tags: gruntjs, uglifyjs

Maybe I'm missing something here but, I'm new on grunt and I don't know why my configuration grunt file is not executing or producing my compress file.

**Gruntfile**

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    connect: { // Conexión al servidor local
      server: {
        options: {
          port: 9000,
          base: 'app/'
        }
      }
    },
    watch: { // Configuración de 'watch' con livereload
      project: {
        files: ['app/**/*.js', 'app/**/*.html', 'app/**/*.json', 'app/**/*.css'],
        options: {
          livereload: true
        }
      }
    },
    uglify: {
      my_target: {
        files: {
          'app-dist/js/app.min.js': 'app/app.js'
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify'); 

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['connect', 'watch', 'uglify']);

};
```

I'm not getting any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watch is a blocking task and prevents uglify from being run. Changing an order of tasks should help

`grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify', 'connect', 'watch']);`

Note: In most of the cases you would want to put it to the very end of your task chain.

Comment: Thanks for your recomendation also ;-)